# Eclipse Java: using existing source-code as different packages (due to visibility)

Tags: java, eclipse, package, visibility

I have 3 different Java-projects:

```
Project A: some basic functionality (Package: "com.a.b.c")
Project B: should be a library and uses A (Package: "com.b.c.d")
Project C: should be a library and uses A (Package: "com.c.d.e")
```

When I give away libraries from B and C, I want the functionality from A to be completely hidden within the libraries, so I'm thinking about package-visibility, but don't want to copy the source-code from A to B and C (changing the package accordingly).
Can I somehow link the source-code from A to B and C, so that its package is interpreted differently depending on the other (linking) project?
Example: Project C sees the source-code from Project A, as if it would be part of its own package.

Hope that's understandable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That you speak of "Projects" implies to me that you are not using Plug-Ins, right? Otherwise B and C could be a fragment to A.
I would "link" the projects B and C to a exported JAR, or even nest the JAR of project A in B and C.

Why does C have to see the "source code" of A?

Comment: I wanted B and C to be able to use package-visible classes/methods from A without givin the user of B and C the possibility to use them. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in Java. I like to see packages in Java as a kind of module. So package visible members/classes offer functionality, which is only needed inside the module, but too big to be put into a single class (where it would be private). Letting B or C access package visible elements would break the encapsulation of module A (unfortunately packages in Java are more of a naming convention, not an intrinsic module mechanic).

So you want to let B and C interact with the public interface of module A. What you want to achieve is in my understanding, to restrict who can use the interface of module A - this is not possible in Java. In fact all the visibility levels in Java do not offer protection from "unauthorized" use. Package visibility can be broken by defining the accessing class in the same package (even if it is in another .jar), private and protected can be broken through reflection.

If you want to hide A to prevent theft, you could use an source code obfuscator, to make decompilation/reengineering harder.